# can`t import http and other library to andorid studio project

Tags: android, http

I am working on a project in android studio and I want to read html source code from url, my code needs to import some libraries and for some reason I can't import them and they change the color to grey

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

Comment: Doesn't gray color just mean they aren't being used? There is no problem unless an actual error marker is on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Add `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` to your app build.gradle as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
```

Refer this link (Section: Apache HTTP Client Removal) : [Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To
>   continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> android {
>       useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }

Also check if the gradle tools you use are updated to `classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0` in top level build.gradle

Comment: I had added this line to build.gardle(Module: app)
and still have the same issue

Comment: also check if your gradle tools are updated to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0` in top level build.gradle